# "Trust anchor for certification path not found" when user clears cache

Tags: android, ssl, caching, networking, httpurlconnection

In my app, when the user manually clears the application cache, they will start getting the error "Trust anchor for certification path not found".

My setup is as follows: the app has a hardcoded URL of a central server. This central server will tell the app the URL of the API that it can log into. When connecting to the central server, the app creates a sync account and stores this url as UserData in the sync account.

When the user clears their cache, after logging in, they will start getting this exception, which will persist even when rebooting the device.

However, when they remove the sync account, and log in again through the central server, the problem disappears. This is the code in `URLConnectionHelper` that triggers the problem and the stacktrace. (My code is com.my.package)

```
public static InputStream getInputStream(AppUser appUser, String fullpath, Map<String, ?> params, Method method) throws IOException
{
    URL url = new URL(fullpath + getQuery(params));
    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    if (appUser != null)
        conn.setRequestProperty("X-AuthToken", appUser.getToken());
    if (method == Method.POST || method == Method.PUT)
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod(method.toString());
    conn.connect(); // <-- line 69
    return new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream(), 8192);
}

06-01 12:04:52.441 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
06-01 12:04:52.441 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:409)
06-01 12:04:52.441 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:146)
06-01 12:04:52.441 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:107)
06-01 12:04:52.441 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)
06-01 12:04:52.441 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
06-01 12:04:52.441 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
06-01 12:04:52.446 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
06-01 12:04:52.446 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
06-01 12:04:52.446 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:161)
06-01 12:04:52.446 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at com.my.package.util.URLConnectionHelper.getInputStream(URLConnectionHelper.java:69)
06-01 12:04:52.446 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at com.my.package.util.URLConnectionHelper.getString(URLConnectionHelper.java:103)
06-01 12:04:52.446 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at com.my.package.util.URLConnectionHelper.getJSONObject(URLConnectionHelper.java:117)
06-01 12:04:52.446 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at com.my.package.task.LoginExistingAccountTask.doInBackground(LoginExistingAccountTask.java:59)
06-01 12:04:52.446 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at com.my.package.task.LoginExistingAccountTask.doInBackground(LoginExistingAccountTask.java:23)
06-01 12:04:52.446 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
06-01 12:04:52.446 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
06-01 12:04:52.446 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
06-01 12:04:52.446 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
06-01 12:04:52.446 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
06-01 12:04:52.446 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
06-01 12:04:52.446 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
06-01 12:04:52.446 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:282)
06-01 12:04:52.446 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:202)
06-01 12:04:52.446 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:611)
06-01 12:04:52.446 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
06-01 12:04:52.446 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:405)
06-01 12:04:52.446 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     ... 19 more
06-01 12:04:52.446 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
06-01 12:04:52.446 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     ... 24 more
06-01 12:04:52.446 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
06-01 12:04:52.446 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:409)
06-01 12:04:52.446 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:146)
06-01 12:04:52.446 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:107)
06-01 12:04:52.446 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)
06-01 12:04:52.451 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
06-01 12:04:52.451 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
06-01 12:04:52.451 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
06-01 12:04:52.451 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
06-01 12:04:52.451 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:161)
06-01 12:04:52.451 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at com.my.package.util.URLConnectionHelper.getInputStream(URLConnectionHelper.java:69)
06-01 12:04:52.451 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at com.my.package.util.URLConnectionHelper.getString(URLConnectionHelper.java:103)
06-01 12:04:52.451 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at com.my.package.util.URLConnectionHelper.getJSONObject(URLConnectionHelper.java:117)
06-01 12:04:52.451 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at com.my.package.task.LoginExistingAccountTask.doInBackground(LoginExistingAccountTask.java:59)
06-01 12:04:52.451 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at com.my.package.task.LoginExistingAccountTask.doInBackground(LoginExistingAccountTask.java:23)
06-01 12:04:52.451 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
06-01 12:04:52.451 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
06-01 12:04:52.451 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
06-01 12:04:52.451 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
06-01 12:04:52.451 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
06-01 12:04:52.451 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
06-01 12:04:52.451 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
06-01 12:04:52.451 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:282)
06-01 12:04:52.451 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:202)
06-01 12:04:52.451 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:611)
06-01 12:04:52.451 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
06-01 12:04:52.451 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:405)
06-01 12:04:52.451 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     ... 19 more
06-01 12:04:52.451 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
06-01 12:04:52.451 26902-27032/com.my.package W/System.err:     ... 24 more
```

Comment: "When the user clears their cache" -- what are you storing in cache that is getting cleared? Have you added logging/breakpoints/whatever to see what the URLs are once you start getting the crash, to see what they look like compared to what they should be?

Comment: @CommonsWare I can't think of anything that I explicitly store in the cache that could be relevant. I have a SQLite DB that I use as a cache. The URL and the token are stored on the Sync Account and are not effected by a cache clear. Also, the problem seems to appear only on this particular customer system. On my local test setup the problem doesn't appear. Perhaps it's an Android bug? Perhaps Android stores a certificate on first connecting to this URL, which is cleared on a cache reset, but Android still thinks it's there so it doesn't get reloaded. Or something like that.

Comment: "the problem seems to appear only on this particular customer system" -- how close is your test setup to that system? I can see potential behavior changes based on Android OS version, and I can't rule out changes based upon device manufacturer tinkering. Unless you can reproduce the problem, I have no idea how you would go about addressing it.

Comment: @CommonsWare I was testing with API 19, but I now also reproduced it with APi 23. I guess the main difference is that my local test server has  a different certificate than the customer system. Perhaps they configured something badly, but I just can't reason how clearing the cache consistently triggers the problem.

Comment: I too cannot see where clearing the cache would have an impact, assuming that your URLs in the crashing scenario look to be correct. But, for example, suppose that the cleared cache is causing you to have invalid URLs for some reason. The server issues a server-side redirect in response to the invalid URL, and the redirected-to URL is improperly configured (e.g., `https` with no certificate for that domain). Here, I'm inventing a not-completely-insane scenario that fits the symptoms. Also, it would be interesting to see what happens if the customer clears cache, then terminates your process.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I think I have a theory what may be the problem: my central server uses the same CA as the customer system, but it could be that they did not correctly configure the certification path. I know that Android is a bit stricter about this than most browsers. So if it first connects to my central server, it knows to trust the CA, but if that is cleared, it can't resolve the trust path from the customer system's certificate path. I could verify this theory by directly connecting to the customer system with an android app without the central server in between.

Comment: Hi @wvdz, is the problem still appear with you? Did you solve it? I faced the same issue after clear the cache, I used minSdkVersion 24 and the compileSdkVersion is 29

Comment: I just made a simple change by increasing versionCode and versionName, after that I made a new release and upload it to google console, but I am not sure if this really solves the problem, it is strange behaviour.

Comment: @MohammadAlkhateeb It's a long time ago, but I'm pretty sure the "theory" I posted above was what was actually going on. Our customer has some invalid setup of their Certificate path, which caused Android to reject it.